# Parse an xml file by knowing its folder is in

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing

I'm working on a project and need to parse xml files knowing only the folder they are in, not the files name. In the folder there is only one file.

Answer (score 3):

I'd never assume that the folder contains a single file, and I also wouldn't assume that the folder contains only XML files. People can manipulate folders, you know :-)

That's why I'd enumerate all the files in a folder, single out files that have the .xml extension and parse them as follows:

```
string[] allFiles = Directory.GetFiles(theFolderName);
foreach (string fileName in allFiles)
{
    if (Path.GetExtension(fileName).Equals(".xml", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
    {
        ParseXMLFile(fileName);
    }
}
```

And the `ParseXMLFile` method looks like this:

```
private void ParseXMLFile(string file)
{
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.Load(file);
    // Continue processing content
    // ...
}
```

Please note that even though a file has the .xml extension doesn't necessarily mean it actually *is* a valid XML file, so please add error handling to the above code.